# Dynamic xml handling with php

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I work with many different types of xml files. I load the contents of these into my mysql database. Problem is that i need to define the tags I want to pick everytime.

Is there a php dom object functions that can iterate over all the tags and give them to me.

this is my sample xml

```
<products> 
   <product> 
        <name>Name of product</name> 
        <categories> 
            <category>Apparel</category> 
           <category>Trousers</category> 
           <category>Blue</category>
        </categories> 
        <description>Blue trousers</description>
        <price>599.00</price> <regularPrice>599.00</regularPrice>
   </product>
</products>
```

Output should be NOT the values but the acctual name of the XML tags, in this case it should be
**Products, Product, Name, Categories, category, description, price**

Getting those values I could dynamicly point them via a connection table to always be save in the right table and in the right field.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: But that does not cover the things i want to do? I ahve been reading that over and over again... Maybe a litte in the right direction for a newbie instead of just downvoting..!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try this code it will work as expected **

```
$xmlD = '
 <products> 
   <product> 
        <name>Name of product</name> 
        <categories> 
            <category>Apparel</category> 
           <category>Trousers</category> 
           <category>Blue</category>
        </categories> 
        <description>Blue trousers</description>
        <price>599.00</price> <regularPrice>599.00</regularPrice>
   </product>
</products>
';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlD);

echo $xml->getName() . "<br />";

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
  {
  echo $child->getName(). "<br />";
  foreach($child->children() as $innerChild):
      echo $innerChild->getName(). "<br />";
  endforeach;
 }
```

Comment: It prints every child how can i limit it to only go through one product?